# Confluent Kafka Rest Proxy - Avro Deserialization

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I am trying to use Confluent Kafka REST Proxy to retrieve data in Avro format from one of my topics but unfortunately I get a deserialization error. I am querying the Kafka REST proxy using the following command

```
 curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" 
http://localhost:8082/consumers/my-group/instances/my-consumer/records?timeout=30000
```

And I get as response

```
{
  "error_code": 50002,
  "message": "Kafka error: Error deserializing key/value for partition input-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption."
}
```

and the logs on Kafka Rest Proxy server are:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition input-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

The data have been produced using KafkaAvroSerializer  and the schema is present on the Schema Registry. Also note that data are readable by using avro-console-consumer on CLI.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that as well as valid Avro messages on the topic, you also have invalid ones. That's what this error means, and is exactly the error that I got when I tried to consume a non-Avro message locally with the REST Proxy:

```
ERROR Unexpected exception in consumer read task id=io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask@2e20d4f3  (io.confluent.kafkarest.v2.KafkaConsumerReadTask)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition avrotest-0 at offset 2. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

I would use a tool such as `kafkacat` to inspect the actual messages at the offset given in the error, e.g.:

```
kafkacat -C -b localhost:9092 -t test_topic_avro -o 0 -c 1
```

The `-o 0` will consume the message at offset 0, and `-c 1` means consume just one message.

You can also [seek past the problematic offset](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#post--consumers-(string-group_name)-instances-(string-instance)-positions), e.g. for topic `avrotest` move the offset to `1`:

```
echo '{ "offsets": [ { "topic": "avrotest", "partition": 0, "offset": 1 } ] }' | \
http POST localhost:8082/consumers/rmoff_consumer_group/instances/rmoff_consumer_instance/positions \
Content-Type:application/vnd.kafka.v2+json
```

Comment: Ok I can commit a message and move on to the next but the issue remains. On the other hand  I can also read the messages using kafka-topics-ui. Could the issue be that I use different serializers for the key (StringSerializer) and the value (KafkaAvroSerializer) ?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't supported to have String keys and AVRO values in the rest proxy until recently:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/210

So recently that the code has been merged, but issue is still open and docs haven't been updated fully:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/pull/797